# Finding a string within a file and outputting results

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, grep, ack

I would like grab one line (1 term) at a time from file1.txt and search sFile.txt... outputting all the lines that have the found term in it. **file1.txt (300 lines) sFile.txt (100k lines)**. I would like to use a command line (linux) `fgrep`, `ack`, `find`, etc. I have tried a fgrep command but I am hitting the character limit so nothing is being processed.

tried: `fgrep -wi 'front1' test.log >> final.txt` this worked but when adding `file1.txt` the process was not able to run

**file1.txt** structure (case insensitive)

```
front1
front2
FrOnT3
```

**sFile.txt** structure

```
106.4 - - [12/Aug/2020:10:46:57 -0400] "GET /skin/front1/sharp_bootstrap/default/css"
106.4 - - [12/Aug/2020:10:46:57 -0400] "GET /skin/front3/sharp_bootstrap/default/css"
106.4 - - [12/Aug/2020:10:46:57 -0400] "GET /skin/front2/sharp_bootstrap/default/css"
106.4 - - [12/Aug/2020:10:46:57 -0400] "GET /skin/front0/sharp_bootstrap/default/css"
```

**final.txt** three lines should have been found

```
106.4 - - [12/Aug/2020:10:46:57 -0400] "GET /skin/front1/sharp_bootstrap/default/css"
106.4 - - [12/Aug/2020:10:46:57 -0400] "GET /skin/front3/sharp_bootstrap/default/css"
106.4 - - [12/Aug/2020:10:46:57 -0400] "GET /skin/front2/sharp_bootstrap/default/css"
```

Comment: not sure why this was tagged as `python` related.

Comment: Is it supposed to be in ServerFault? https://serverfault.com/

Comment: *when adding file1.txt the process was not able to run* And how did you add it?

Comment: *am hitting the character limit* What character limit?

Comment: What is the output/errors of `grep -f file1.txt sFile.txt` ?

Comment: @thanasisp nothing is outputted ... but if I add 2-3 lines in file1.txt and process it against sFile.txt it outputs results with no problems. Full 300 lines seems to be too much... I read that grep has a 2048 character limit

Comment: I realize the `fgrep --man` output is a bit much to take in all at once. You need an `-f srchListFile.txt` argument in an `fgrep` cmd. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution... [Source for Solution](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/grep-for-huge-files-826030/page2.html)

```
fgrep -v -F -f file1.txt sFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modifying what @thanasisp said, are you not getting the desired output if you use the below?

```
grep -if file1.txt sFile.txt
```